# Alguien sabe como bloquear el acceso a mi sitio web a personas que usan el navegador de Tor

Tags: php

Tengo un sitio web, un pequeño blog que he construido con PHP y quiero que no este disponible para persona que entran desde el navegador **Tor**

Resulta que hace unos días atrás un hacker logro penetrar la seguridad de mi sitio web y entro a mis sistema y manipulo mi base de datos y todo apunta a que utilizaba el navegador Tor para hacer esta acción. Y es por esa razón que quiero bloquear el acceso a mi sitio web a las personas que usen Tor.

No estoy seguro si debo mostrar algún código o algún tipo de información para que me puedan ayudar, si es así por favor solo háganmelo saber.

Comment: puedes utilizar esta libreria https://github.com/dapphp/TorUtils/blob/master/examples/TorDNSEL.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes implementar CloudFlare en tu sitio.

Creas tu cuenta de CloudFlare, agregas las configuraciones DNS correspondientes para que CloudFlare sea ahora el que entregue las peticiones antes de que lleguen a tu servidor.

Y, en las configuraciones de Firewall > Reglas de Firewall > Agregar regla solamente incluyes una regla de tipo "Continente", en el valor seleccionas "Tor"y en la acción le pones "Bloquear".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Automáticamente, CloudFlare se encarga de filtrar las peticiones que vengan de nodos conocidos que se usen para navegación con Tor